# How to list files in a sftp from scala using akka.stream.alpakka.ftp?

Tags: scala, akka, sftp

In my Scala code I have:

```scala
val ftpApi: FtpApi[SSHClient, SftpSettings]

val futureResult = ftpApi.ls(basePath = path, connectionSettings = settings)
```

this generetes this output:

```
11:53:36.875 [sshj-Reader-/200.13.144.60:181] DEBUG net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Setting active service to null-service
11:53:36.875 [sshj-Reader-/200.13.144.60:181] DEBUG net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise - Setting <<transport close>> to `SOME`
11:53:36.875 [sshj-Reader-/200.13.144.60:181] DEBUG net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader - Stopping
[ERROR] [02/27/2023 11:53:36.876] [default-akka.actor.default-blocking-io-dispatcher-21] [akka://default/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-0-2-sFtpBrowserSource] Error during postStop in [akka.stream.alpakka.ftp.impl.FtpBrowserGraphStage$$anon$1-sFtpBrowserSource]: Broken transport; encountered EOF
net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionException: Broken transport; encountered EOF
    at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionException$1.chain(ConnectionException.java:32)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionException$1.chain(ConnectionException.java:26)
    at net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise.deliverError(Promise.java:95)
    at net.schmizz.concurrent.Event.deliverError(Event.java:74)
    at net.schmizz.concurrent.ErrorDeliveryUtil.alertEvents(ErrorDeliveryUtil.java:34)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.AbstractChannel.notifyError(AbstractChannel.java:239)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.direct.SessionChannel.notifyError(SessionChannel.java:229)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.common.ErrorNotifiable$Util.alertAll(ErrorNotifiable.java:35)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionImpl.notifyError(ConnectionImpl.java:261)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.die(TransportImpl.java:588)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:66)
Caused by: net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: Broken transport; encountered EOF
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:58)
```

I expected that this will list the files in the sftp.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have the `FtpApi` but with `SftpSettings`.
You may directly use

for FTP:

```
val source: Source[FtpFile, NotUsed] = Ftp.ls(sourcePath, ftpSettings)
```

for SFTP:

```
val source: Source[FtpFile, NotUsed] = Sftp.ls(sourcePath, sftpSettings)
```

The Alpakka (S)FTP implementation has a few quirks. For what it's worth, [this working SFTP example](https://github.com/pbernet/akka_streams_tutorial/blob/master/src/main/scala/alpakka/sftp/SftpEcho.scala) is an attempt to show what is possible.